# Rails4 - How to pass value properly in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using metamagic gem to create meta tags for facebook.
I have this in my rails app.

```
<%
meta og: {
title: "Mywebsite.com - " + @micropost.user.name,
type: "article",
description: ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(@micropost.content)
}
%>
```

I am trying to add url and image property.

```
<%
meta og: {
title: "Mywebsite.com - " + @micropost.user.name,
type: "article",
description: ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(@micropost.content)
url:
image:
}
%>
```

I want the url and image to be taken from the following.

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/microposts/<%= @micropost.id %>
<%= image_tag @micropost.user.avatar.url(:preview), :style => "display: none;" %>
```

But I always get errors. When I don't get errors, I get only

```
/micropost/15
/image/1/something.png
```

How do I the supply the complete values? Like

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/microposst/15
https://www.mywebsite.com/image/1/something.png
```

I tried double qoutes and single qoutes. But nothing seems to work.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<% img = "<img src="+ micropost.user.avatar.url(:preview) +" style='display: none;'>" %> 

<%
meta og: {
title: "Mywebsite.com - " + @micropost.user.name,
type: "article",
description: ActionView::Base.full_sanitizer.sanitize(@micropost.content),
url: "https://www.mywebsite.com/microposts/" + @micropost.id.to_s,
image: img.html_safe
}
%>
```

Comment: you are usind '<% .. %>' for url & image inside '<% .. %>'